# The dbo.ASPNetUser and the other tables like this don't appear in my Server Explorer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, web, backend

I am working in my MVC5 project and I have created a DbContext different to the ApplicationDbContext but it inherits from the same class. I have been developing some parts of my project but now I want to add all the authentication and authorization stuff. But the tables that ASP.NET creates automatically for this purpose don't show up in my Server Explorer although I can work with the sets named Users and Roles of my context. I have searched the reasons of this but I found nothing useful. I hope someone can answer my question and whether it is an important issue or not. I add the code of my DbContext class. Sorry for my English cause I know it is terrible.

```
      namespace GestionPaladares.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;
    using GestionPaladares.Models;
    using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
    using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;


    public class PaladarContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        // Your context has been configured to use a 'CodeFirstDatabaseModel' connection string from your application's 
        // configuration file (App.config or Web.config). By default, this connection string targets the 
        // 'GestionPaladares.Models.CodeFirstDatabaseModel' database on your LocalDb instance. 
        // 
        // If you wish to target a different database and/or database provider, modify the 'CodeFirstDatabaseModel' 
        // connection string in the application configuration file.
        public PaladarContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {

        }

        // Add a DbSet for each entity type that you want to include in your model. For more information 
        // on configuring and using a Code First model, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=390109.

        public virtual DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<FoodAndDrink> Foods { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<SoldBill> SoldBills { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<CostBill> CostBills { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Seller> Sellers { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Grocer> Grocers { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Owner> Owners { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Measure> Measures { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Edge> Edges { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add ApplicationUser in Dbcontext

```
public DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUser { get; set; }
```

For example,

```
namespace GestionPaladares.Models
{
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;
using GestionPaladares.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;


public class PaladarContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    // Your context has been configured to use a 'CodeFirstDatabaseModel' connection string from your application's 
    // configuration file (App.config or Web.config). By default, this connection string targets the 
    // 'GestionPaladares.Models.CodeFirstDatabaseModel' database on your LocalDb instance. 
    // 
    // If you wish to target a different database and/or database provider, modify the 'CodeFirstDatabaseModel' 
    // connection string in the application configuration file.
    public PaladarContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {

    }

    // Add a DbSet for each entity type that you want to include in your model. For more information 
    // on configuring and using a Code First model, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=390109.

    public virtual DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<FoodAndDrink> Foods { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<SoldBill> SoldBills { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<CostBill> CostBills { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Seller> Sellers { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Grocer> Grocers { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Owner> Owners { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Measure> Measures { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Edge> Edges { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUser { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

    }
}

}
```

Comment: I have noted that the ApplicationDbContext that comes by default with the MVC project don't add it and I have seen how Entity Framework creates the tables anyway in other projects that uses this context. Why it doesn't do the same with my own context if it inherits from the same class?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using EF, you should first add migration, then do update database from the PM console window. Take a note you have to select the correct project form the list and be sure of the right connection string in your code or appsettings file.

Or, you have to create your own method to call on startup for fixing the database for you.

```
public static void EnsureDatabaseCreated(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    using (var context = new DatabaseContext(configuration.GetConnectionString(GlobalConstants.APP_SETTINGS_CONNECTION_NAME)))
    {
        context.Database.Migrate();
    }
}


public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IHostingEnvironment environment)
{
    EnsureDatabaseCreated(this.configuration);
}
```

Change the DatabaseContext class name with yours.

Hope this helps.